# show a specific view when application returns to foreground

Tags: ios4, uilocalnotification, background-foreground

I have a voip application

The application enters a background mode on pressing Home button. When the application receive incoming call notification it creates a UILocalNotification and fires it immediately. The user sees the alert with close and answer buttons. When he presses Answer button the application moves back to foreground. Currently it gets back exactly where the user left it to the background. I'd like to show at this stage another view like default.png picture and hide all previous views.

What is the very first function I can use as an entry point for this purpose?

When I come to applicationWillEnterForeground, the application **already** shows previous state. applicationDidBecomeActive is called after that. didReceiveLocalNotification is really late. Any ideas?
TIA

EDIT:
To rephrase the question: I don't want my GUI to redraw itself when the application enters foreground. How do I achieve it?